# Why is the code accepted by clang but rejected by vc++?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11, compiler-errors, clang

clang 3.4 accepts the following code; while vc++ NOV 2013 CTP rejects it with an error:

```
error C2668: 'AreEqual' : ambiguous call to overloaded function
```

```cpp
template<class headT, class... tailTypes>
constexpr headT&& __GetFirst__(headT&& value, tailTypes&&...)
{
    return static_cast<headT&&>(value);
};

template<class T>
constexpr bool AreEqual(const T& a, const T& b)
{   
    return a == b;
}

template<class headT, class... tailTypes>
constexpr bool AreEqual(const headT& head_value, const tailTypes&... tail_values)
{
    return AreEqual(head_value, __GetFirst__(tail_values...))
           && AreEqual(tail_values...);
}

int main()
{
    AreEqual(1, 1, 2, 1);  
}
```

Which compiler is correct as per the C++14 standard?

Update: The full error message:

```
error C2668: 'AreEqual' : ambiguous call to overloaded function
1>          d:\projects\ktl\test\main.cpp(20): could be 'bool AreEqual<headT,int>(const headT &,const int &)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              headT=int
1>          ]
1>          d:\projects\ktl\test\main.cpp(8): or       'bool AreEqual<headT>(const T &,const T &)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              headT=int
1>  ,            T=int
1>          ]
1>          while trying to match the argument list '(const int, const int)'
1>
1>Build FAILED.
```

Comment: Side note: `__GetFirst__` is a reserved name.

Comment: Can you post the full error message please?

Comment: don't know which is correct, but easy fix is having variadic take 3+ params

Comment: +1 thanks. Removed the syntax coloring from the error message for you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Clang (and GCC)'s behavior is correct. You can read §14.8.2.4 [temp.deduct.partial] of the standard for how the partial ordering for function templates is done, but the example given in p8 of that subclause directly covers this situation:

```
template<class... Args> void f(Args... args); // #1
template<class T1, class... Args> void f(T1 a1, Args... args); // #2
template<class T1, class T2> void f(T1 a1, T2 a2); // #3
f(); // calls #1
f(1, 2, 3); // calls #2
f(1, 2); // calls #3; non-variadic template #3 is more
         // specialized than the variadic templates #1 and #2
```

Comment: +1. Also added the `[bracked subsection]` identifier for that sub clause to make it easier to find in different versions of the standard. (The specific clause #s move around but those identifiers are fixed)

Comment: @BillyONeal I'd quarrel about those identifiers being fixed (`basic.lookup.koenig`->`basic.lookup.argdep` :)) but point taken.